# Finding the 9th derivative of a Power Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Given the infinite series:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(x-2)^{2n+1}}{n^22^n}$$

How would I be able to find the 9th derivative evaluated at $x = 2$ knowing that:

$f^{(n)}(a) = c_nn!$

Where $c_n$ is the Taylor coefficient.

I am able to do a similar question (below) where the exponent is simply $n$ but I can't seem to figure out the first one.

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(x-2)^{n}}{n^22^n}$$

Comment: That was supposed to be the Taylor coefficient at a given n. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Hint :  for what value of $n$ does $2n+1=9$?

Comment: Hint: if you can solve with exponent $n$, then you can solve with exponent $2n+1$. Really.

Answer (score 2):

The $9^{th}$ derivative is associated to the coefficient of $(x-2)^9$.  This corresponds to $n = 4$.

Comment: So $f^4 = c_4 4! = \frac{4!}{4^22^4}$? Is this correct?

Comment: Looks right to me.